# warning: passing argument 2 makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, punteros

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
void buscapareja1 (int n,int *a, int *b);
void buscapareja2 (int n, int a, int *b);
bool pitagoricos (int h, int *c1, int *c2);   


int main() {
    int hipo, cmenor, cmayor;
    cmenor=1;
    cmayor=1;
    
    printf("introduce el primer número");
    scanf( "%d", &hipo);
    while (hipo != 0){
        buscapareja1 (hipo, &cmenor, &cmayor);
        if (pitagoricos (hipo, &cmenor, &cmayor)==true){
            printf("Hipotenusa: %i \n",hipo);
            printf("Cateto menor %i \n",cmenor);
            printf("Cateto myor %i \n", cmayor);
        } else
        {
            printf("introduce el siguiente numero");
            scanf( "%d", &hipo);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}                 

void buscapareja1 (int n,int *a, int *b){
    bool encontrado= false;
    *a=1;
    *b=1;
    while (*a < n && encontrado==false){
        buscapareja2 (n,a,b);
        encontrado==pitagoricos(n,a,b);
        if (encontrado=false){
            *a=*a+1;
        }

    } 
    return; 
}

            
void buscapareja2 (int n, int a, int *b){
    bool encontrado= false;
    *b=1;
    while (*b < n && encontrado==false){
        encontrado==pitagoricos(n,a,b);
        if (encontrado=false){
            *b=*b+1;
        }

    } 
    return; 
}

bool pitagoricos (int h, int *c1, int *c2){
    if (h*h==*c1**c1+*c2**c2)
    {
        return true;
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
        
}
```

Cuando compilé el programa me salió este error:

> [Warning]assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Y aquí me aparece este error:

> note: expected 'int' but argument is of type 'int *'.

Estos errores se repiten a lo largo del código ya que no entiendo muy bien como pasar punteros entre varias funciones.

El programa consiste en dada unos números enteros `h`, hipotenusa, mostrar por pantalla los catetos que formen ternas pitagóricas si las tuviera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En primer lugar, haces una comparación cuando en realidad tienes que hacer una asignación:

```
encontrado==pitagoricos(n,a,b);
```

Esto debería de ser:

```
encontrado=pitagoricos(n,a,b);
```

En segundo lugar la cabecera de la función:

```
void buscapareja2 (int n, int a, int *b);
```

Debería ser:

```
void buscapareja2 (int n, int *a, int *b);
```

Y en tercer lugar en el bucle tienes un fallo, y es que, en el caso de que se encuentre una combinación de catetos que haga a `pitagóricos` devolver `true` se queda en un bucle infinito porque no das la oportunidad de modificar el valor de la hipotenusa, es decir, no se ejecuta el `scanf`.

La solución sería:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void buscapareja1 (int n,int *a, int *b);
void buscapareja2 (int n, int *a, int *b);
bool pitagoricos (int h, int *c1, int *c2);   


int main() {
    int hipo, cmenor, cmayor;
    cmenor=1;
    cmayor=1;
    
    printf("introduce el primer número: ");
    scanf( "%d", &hipo);
    while (hipo != 0){
        buscapareja1 (hipo, &cmenor, &cmayor);
        if (pitagoricos (hipo, &cmenor, &cmayor)==true){
          printf("Hipotenusa: %i \n",hipo);
          printf("Cateto menor %i \n",cmenor);
          printf("Cateto myor %i \n", cmayor);
        } else {
          printf("Nope!\n");
        }

        printf("introduce el siguiente numero: ");
        scanf( "%d", &hipo);
    }
    return 0;
}                 

void buscapareja1 (int n,int *a, int *b){
    *a=1;
    *b=1;
    bool encontrado = false;
    while (*a < n && encontrado==false){
        buscapareja2 (n,a,b);
        encontrado=pitagoricos(n,a,b);

        if ( encontrado == false ) {
          (*a)++;
        }
    } 
    return; 
}

            
void buscapareja2 (int n, int *a, int *b){
    bool encontrado= false;
    *b=1;
    while (*b < n && encontrado==false){
        encontrado=pitagoricos(n,a,b);
        if ( encontrado == false ) {
          (*b)++;
        }
    } 
    return; 
}

bool pitagoricos (int h, int *c1, int *c2){
    return h*h==*c1**c1+*c2**c2;
}
```